# Execute program even if all scanf() values were not assigned

Tags: c

I would like to check if there is an invalid input. I do this by asking if return value of `scanf()` is equal to arguments. If not its a wrong input.

But what if user doesn't enter all 12 values? The program is just keep waiting for inputs and doesn't care. I just want to execute it with less arguments.

For instance those inputs:

1. 00

   999.990 204.330

   899.991 183.897
2. 1 2
   3 abcd

Code in C:

```
double bod1A[2], bod1B[2], bod1C[2], bod2A[2], bod2B[2], bod2C[2];

if(scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&bod1A[0], &bod1A[1],
                                                           &bod1B[0], &bod1B[1],
                                                           &bod1C[0], &bod1C[1],
                                                           &bod2A[0], &bod2A[1],
                                                           &bod2B[0], &bod2B[1],
                                                           &bod2C[0], &bod2C[1]) != 12)
{
    printf("Wrong Input.");
}
```

Comment: You could read an entire line of input as a string, then try and parse it separately

Comment: Or you could use a loop.

Comment: Thx for the suggestions, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Using a loop would help, @Swordfish, but only at restructuring the code above. It wouldn't change its behaviour...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Not sure what you are trying to say. Would you rephrase, please?

Comment: Reading `N` values calls for a loop, right. The problem here is how to handle different kinds of user input, different numbers of input fields.